# How to check SSL certificate encryption with ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, encryption

i am new on Ruby and got the task to check the encryption of some SSL certificates to figure out if they use sha1 or sha256. I do not have any idea.

here a code snippet which checks for expiring date and has to be extended with encryption info:

```
  domains.each do |domain|
  domain_name = domain[:Name]

  begin
    uri = URI.parse("https://" + domain_name)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    http.start do |h|
      @cert = h.peer_cert
  end

  expire_date = Date.parse(@cert.not_after.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).to_s

  output('INFO', 'SSL expiry date is: ' + expire_date.to_s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`OpenSSL::X509::Certificate#signature_algorithm`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html#method-i-signature_algorithm)

```
@cert.signature_algorithm
#=> sha1WithRSAEncryption
```